# Visualizing large data sets with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, plot, data-visualization, bigdata

I'm looking for a framework, a combination of frameworks, best-practices, or a tutorial about visualizing large data sets with Hadoop.

I am **not** looking for a framework to visualize the mechanics of running Hadoop jobs or managing disk space on Hadoop.  I am looking for an approach or a guideline for visualizing the data contained within HDFS using graphs and charts, etc.

For example, let's say I have a set of data points stored in multiple files in HDFS, and I would like to show a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of the data.  Is my only option to write a custom map/reduce job that would try and figure out which points fall into which bucket, write the totals to a file, and then use a plotting library to visualize that?

Do I need to roll out a custom solution, or is there anyone else doing this sort of thing out there?  I've trying looking online, but I haven't been able to find something that directly relates to this.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

We do something like this at [Datameer](http://www.datameer.com/product/data-visualization.html). The files would take a few more processing steps to get to our visualizations, but we run natively on Hadoop so the files would not be far away.